# Extracting detail records of XML via C# LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML excerpt. I have no problem extracting the first step of XML but I can't figure out how to get to the second layer and extract each layer. Specifically, the user info in XML below.

Any help will be appreciated...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
    <ns2:getStatusReportResponse xmlns:ns2="http://xxxxxxxxx.com/">
      <return>
        <statusReport>
        <record>
          <assessorDate /> 
          <assessorOffice /> 
          <availableDate /> 
          <awardDate>01/01/2014</awardDate> 
          <awardValue>1000000</awardValue> 
              <businessSector>SYSTEMS</businessSector> 
          <user>
            <accessGrantedDate /> 
            <emailAddress>john.usda@noemail.mil</emailAddress> 
            <name>JOHN USDA</name> 
            <phoneNumber>XXX-XXX-XXXX</phoneNumber> 
            <role>Focal Point</role> 
          </user>
          <user>
            <accessGrantedDate /> 
            <emailAddress>john.usda@noemail.mil</emailAddress> 
            <name>JOHN USDA</name> 
            <phoneNumber>XXX-XXX-XXXX</phoneNumber> 
            <role>Focal Point</role> 
          </user>
        </record>
       </statusReport>
      </return>
    </ns2:getStatusReportResponse>
    </S:Body>
  </S:Envelope>
```

I've tried this but it only get's me a list of the first user record and not all of them.

```
var records = from x in xml.Descendants("record")
              select new
              {
                  awardDate = (string) x.Descendants("awardDate").FirstOrDefault().Value
                  ,userList = (List<string>) x.Descendants("user").Elements()                                                                //.Elements("accessGrantedDate")
                                                                  .Select(a => a.Value).ToList()
              };
```

Comment: Do you want the complete record or only the user nodes?

Comment: my goal is to have the details for each record that i can tie back to parent.

Comment: Are you sure a `List<string>` is what you want? Why not a `List<User>`?

Comment: ah. so create a class of User.  That would be exactly what I want. Sorry, I'm a SQL developer and only written a handful of C#. Would my logic work if i changed List<string> to list<user>?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ran with the list idea you gave me and actually created a list within a list to solve the problem. I marked you as solved since I'm sure you solution works and you sent me in the direction to come up with my solution.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I see that you and the other guy are changing my descendants.firstordefault logic to element. is that proper programming i should change to? Does element have to be on the same level as xml.Descendants("record")? I guess using element assumes value?

Comment: Yes, it is proper programming. Calling `Descendants` will iterate through all child elements. Calling `Element` with a cast as i'm doing accesses the `Value` property of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming this is the model of your `User` class:

```
public class User
{
    public DateTime? AccessGrantedDate { get; set; }
    public string EMailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

And this is extracting the `User` class from the XML:

```
var records = from x in xml.Descendants("record")
              select new
              {
                 AwardDate = (string)x.Element("awardDate"),
                 UserList = x.Descendants("user").Select(user => new User 
                 {
                    AccessGrantedDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)user.Element("accessGrantedDate")) ? 
                                        (DateTime?) null : DateTime.Parse((string)user.Element("accessGrantedDate")),
                    EMailAddress = (string)user.Element("emailAddress"),
                    Name = (string)user.Element("name"),
                    PhoneNumber = (string)user.Element("phoneNumber"),
                    Role = (string)user.Element("role")
                 })
              };
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your code gets the data of all users in the file, but only the values of nodes.

The more organized way to do this would be:

```
class User
    {
        public string accessGrantedDate { get; set; }
        public string emailAddress { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }       
        public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string role { get; set; }       
    }
```

then:

```
var records = from x in xml.Descendants("record")
              select new
              {
                  awardDate = (string) x.Descendants("awardDate").FirstOrDefault().Value
                  ,userList = x.Descendants("user").Select(a=>new User
                  {
                        accessGrantedDate= a.Element("accessGrantedDate").Value,
                        emailAddress=a.Element("emailAddress").Value,
                        name=a.Element("name").Value,
                        phoneNumber=a.Element("phoneNumber").Value,
                        role = a.Element("role").Value
                  }).ToList()
              };
```

or, if you don't want to organize your data this way, you may use a list of lists:

```
 var records = from x in xml.Descendants("record")
        select new
        {
            awardDate = (string)x.Descendants("awardDate").FirstOrDefault().Value,
            userList = x.Descendants("user").Select(a => a.Elements().Select(b=>b.Value).ToList()).ToList()
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using a 2nd query for detail records, therefore, creating a List as a object inside the outer list.

```
        var records = from x in xml.Descendants("record")
                      select new
                      {
                          awardDate = x.Element("awardDate")
                          ,
                          userList = from u in x.Descendants("user")
                                     select new
                                       {
                                           accessGrantedDate = (string) u.Element("accessGrantedDate")
                                           ,emailAddress =(string) u.Element("emailAddress"
                                           ,name = (string) u.Element("name")
                                           ,phoneNumber = (string) u.Element("phoneNumber")
                                           ,role = (string) u.Element("role")
                                       }
                      };
```

Comment: Your iteration using `Descendants` is redundant here. You can access each element by using the `Element()` method.